# script that uses xclip not working from keyboard shortcut

Tags: 20.04, bash, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xclip

Output of `uname -a`: `Linux negosaki 5.11.0-46-lowlatency #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 7 08:04:34 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I have the following script in `~/bin/flameshot-ocr`, which is in my path:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function ocr() {

filename=$1
lang=$2
outfile="/tmp/tesseract-output"

tesseract "$1" $outfile -l "$2"
cat "$outfile".txt
}

save_path="/tmp/flameshot-screenshot.png"
lang=$1

flameshot gui -r > "$save_path"
output=$(ocr "$save_path" "$lang")
echo "$output"
echo "$output" | xclip -selection clipboard
yomichan-search
exit 0
```

The `yomichan-search` command is just another command I have in my path which uses `xdotool` to bring a program I use to focus.
Basically, the script uses `flameshot` to prompt me for a cropped screenshot, then saves that screenshot to `/tmp/flameshot-screenshot.png`, and then uses tesseract with the provided language option to perform ocr on the image, and saves the result in `/tmp/tesseract-output.txt`. Then, I use xclip to copy this output to my system clipboard. This all works when I run the script from my terminal, e.g. `flameshot-ocr jpn_vert`. However, when I run it with a keyboard shortcut (the command `flameshot-ocr jpn_vert`, only part of the script runs: I get prompted for a screenshot, the screenshot gets saved, tesseract is run on it, but the output does not get copied to my clipboard (xclip fails), and my `yomichan-search` script doesn't run.
For reference, here is my `yomichan-search` script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ $(xdotool search yomichan)  ]]; then
    xdotool search yomichan windowactivate
else
    /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=dmlhnpobnomcmidkoijomppdlpfkedmi
fi
```

I have verified that a simple command like `echo "hello | xclip -selection clipboard"` works when I run it from my terminal, but not from a keyboard shortcut, and I have tried
`sh -c 'echo "hello" | xclip -selection clipboard'` in the keyboard shortcut, which does work, but a keyboard shortcut like `sh -c 'flameshot-ocr jpn_vert'` just does the exact same thing as when I didn't wrap it in `sh -c`.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that your system has fully-upgraded?  as the 5.11 kernel should have been replaced by the 5.13 kernel within the last 48+ hours.  Ensure your system is fully upgraded with all security fixes applied.

Comment: yes it was updated to 5.13, then I noticed frequent crashes and downgraded to 5.11 after which the crashes have stopped. But I have solved my all question, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing `xclip` and `yomichan-search` to the absolute paths to those scripts.